# sqlcmd not running

Tags: sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I am not a SQL specialist, but I really need to use the `sqlcmd` utility.

I have installed

[image]

but when I run `sqlcmd`, I get

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn>sqlcmd
```

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

Can you give a help hand please ?

I really need to attach a `.mdf` file to my SQL Server 2012 machine

Comment: The error says you cannot connect. So you need to troubleshoot that. Obviously that is not the actual cmd line you ran right? you put a SQL Server instance name in there etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are missing the instance name -
usage:
`sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName>`